# How can I type a generic component that takes as one of its arguments a function that returns an AxiosResponse?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a generic component that takes a render prop and a request prop, and uses the response from that request to render components specified in its render prop. How can I type the interface for that component? So far I tried

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { ScrollBox } from 'components/atoms';
import { IProps as ScrollBoxProps } from 'components/atoms/ScrollBox/ScrollBox';
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface IProps extends ScrollBoxProps {
  request: (args?: unknown) => Promise<void | AxiosResponse<never>>;
  render: (args?: unknown) => ReactNode;
}

export const FetchBox: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  rounded,
  title,
  height,
  request,
  render,
}) => {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      const response = await request();
      setList(response?.data.data);
    };
    makeRequest();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollBox rounded={rounded} title={title} height={height}>
      {list?.map((element) => render(element))}
    </ScrollBox>
  );
};

export default FetchBox;
```

But if I do this, I get a type error when trying to destructure the `data` key from the response data (Property 'data' does not exist on type 'never').
All of the functions passed to the request prop are going to return Axios promises. How do I go about typing that interface?

Comment: provide reproducible example

Comment: You mean like a codesandbox example or just the code for the whole component that I'm asking about?

Comment: it is better to include both: minimum reproducible example into the question and link to sandbox

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with the full component. If that's not enough then I can try creating a working example on the sandbox, but it's probably going to take a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example. You can type directly the response of Axios (in your example I have also typed the args of the 2 functions)

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';



interface IProps<T, U, V>  {   // note the typing
  request: (args?: U) => Promise< void | AxiosResponse<T>>;
  render: (args?: V) => ReactNode;
}

export const FetchBox: React.FC<IProps<number, string, string>> = ({
  
  request,
  render,
}) => {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(undefined);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      const response = await request();
      setList(response && response.data); // note the test here to handle when return type is void
    };
    makeRequest();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {list?.map((element) => render(element))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FetchBox;
```

Comment: What if I don't know the exact number of arguments in the incoming functions? Doesn't that make a difference when typing the component specifically with <number, string, string>?

Comment: if the functions have args, then it shoud be typing as (...args:U[]). args are always an array. If you din't know the type of args, and even the return type of the request function then I would say that using a generic is not what I would do, because at the end, using any or unknown is killing type safety. however you can do IProps<T,U =any,V=any>

Answer (score 0):

Made a dummy example for you,
Added the example in codesandbox, basically what I understand is that your Array of objects can have different types
Lets say Array of Apple or Array of Oranges, and you want to generalise them.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-lake-7u4gx?file=/src/App.tsx

You can achieve this using a generic.

```
<FetchBox<Args> />
```

```
const FetchBox = <T extends any>({ request, render }: IProps<T>) => {
```

And for your Props

you can do something like

```
interface IProps<T> {
  request: (
    args?: T
  ) => Promise<
    AxiosResponse<{
      data: T[];
    }>
  >;
  render: (args?: T) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

[image: Here as you can see Typescript inferred the type for args]

Comment: this gets rid of the TS errors in the FetchBox definition (apart from the linter being unhappy about extending 'any'), but it breaks the props passed into the component in its implementation, unfortunately